# How do I change the order that SyncToy runs folder pairs?

Tags: windows, synctoy

I've setup some folder pairs to run with SyncToy 2.1. Now I want to "Run All" but I want to run them in a different order to which I added them. Is there a way to change the order that the sync pairs will run when I execute "Run All"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that there is no way to change the order of the folder pairs through the SyncToy user interface.

The configuration-file of SyncToy, SyncToyDirPairs.bin, is a binary file of unknown format and cannot be modified.

The only solution I can see is to use a batch (.bat) file containing in the right order commands such as :

```
"C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R "pair name"
```

For more clever ways of using in a batch file (although somewhat over-done), see this thread:
[SyncToy + Batch = Simple Syncing](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/forums.asp?forumid=84&topicid=57743)

Answer (score 3):

From http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/synctoy/thread/650d550a-d8df-491d-b5d6-a160f6dc2c3d:

**Question:**

> How does SyncToy determine the order it will follow when processing the Folder Pairs?  Is it alphabetical?  Can you control the run order of the Folder Pairs?  I have some folders pairs I'd like to ensure will run before another set of folder pairs.

**Answer:**

> The order in which folder pairs are run is the order in which they were created. Otherwise - just manually run them in the order that you want or write a batch file that runs them in the order that you want if you want this to be automated.